# Visits on the main: Day-averages June-Aug 2015

Tags: discussion, site-activity

Continuing to explore main-site Analytics, here are the day-averages for "Visits on the main site", for the period June 8th - Aug 30th 2015 (I excluded the first week of June because it was obviously an outlier for the period):

[image]

Standard deviations range in the $50-100$ interval.

It is obvious(...) that Economics is not a light hobby - so people get down to it during the workweek, reserving the weekend, especially Saturday, in order to rest (relatively).

The current "Visits per day" metric (all days together) stands at $688$.

Answer (score 2):

I also did some excel skills:

### Upvotes per week day, questions versus answers

[image: upvotes per week day]

Things look nicely over the week, perhaps a little downwards trend. On average questions get more upvotes than downvotes.

### Up-down ratio per week day, questions versus answers

[image: up-down ratio per week day]

Note how the ratio is much better for Monday and Saturday, the beginning of week/week end.

Comment: "Note that the ratio is never above 50%". Does this mean that downvotes are always _more than double_ the upvotes? (The vertical axis scale on the 2nd graph is $\%$?)

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Whoups, I checked again and it's wrong. Somehow my import added the leading dot :D. Here's the underlying query: http://data.stackexchange.com/economics/query/1718/up-vs-down-votes-by-day-of-week-of-question-or-answer

Comment: Since downvotes are consistently lower than upvotes, I would suggest to either a) Calculate upvotes/downvotes as an "odds ratio", so not expressed as a percentage (i.e. "how many upvotes per one downvote"), or b) calculate downvotes/upvotes and express it as a percentage.